# New guide line for Apple : "Sign in with Apple" is it only for iOS 13 or we can use it on iOS 10 or below devices?

Tags: ios, sign-in-with-apple

I can run the login module successfully on iOS 13 but nothing happened when you run on iOS 10.
So is it necessary to add "Sign in with Apple" to below iOS 13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sign in with Apple is only supported on iOS 13+. In terms of Apple's review guidelines (that state you must support Sign in with Apple if you have other 3rd party login options), so long as it's supported on iOS 13+ and works correctly, you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the replay Charlie. So we have to show "Sign in with Apple" login button on iOS 13+ but not in iOS13 below. correct?

Comment: @APPP Correct. But you are only required to support `Sign in with Apple` if you also use 3rd party login providers. If you don't use 3rd party login providers, `Sign in with Apple` is optional. Although I'd still recommend it. Pretty sure the `Sign in with Apple` button must be the top button when in a stack of login provider buttons.

Comment: I am using email login (custom login) and Facebook login. Do I need to integrate "Sign in with Apple"

Comment: @APPP Yes. Facebook is a 3rd party login.